# Add arguments cc and bcc blackberry.invoke.MessageArguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, email, blackberry, cordova

I am working a phonegap project for blackberry os 7 and I want to add cc and bcc arguments in email composed blackberry 7 API **blackberry.invoke.MessageArguments ()**

Actually this API accepting only three Arguments toRecipients, subject and email Body. Is there any solution add rest of two arguments cc and bcc. I have used following Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  var args = new blackberry.invoke.MessageArguments('foo@domain.com', 'hello', 'world');
  args.view = blackberry.invoke.MessageArguments.VIEW_NEW; // New

  blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_MESSAGES, args);  // New Message
</script>
```

For more reference see on the following link.
[Blackberry Invoke API for MessagesArguments](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.messagearguments.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building phonegap application then you can use "mailto". I have tested on BlackBerry 7 device and it is woking fine for me.

Sample Code:

```
var sMailTo = "mailto:";        
sMailTo += escape(toRecipient) +"?subject=" +escape(subject) +"&body=" +escape(body) +"&cc=" +escape(ccRecipient);
window.open(sMailTo, '_self');
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "mailto:" and append the params you need to add accordingly.This should work.